# Filtering large set of date/time data down to 15 minute increments in R

Tags: r, time, filter, dplyr

I am trying to use the dplyr::filter function like the below:

```
df <- dplyr::filter(df,grepl(c('%%:00:00','%%:15:00','%%:30:00','%%:45:00'),date_time))
```

but this yields no results.  My date_time field is in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a single string `pattern` inside the `grepl`,  It can be done by `paste` with `|` (OR).  So, it will check either of the vector elements are matched and returns `TRUE/FALSE` for each row to filter those rows

```
pat <- paste(c('%%:00:00','%%:15:00','%%:30:00','%%:45:00'), collapse="|")
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     filter(grepl(pat, date_time))
```

NOTE: The `%%` is not clear as the OP's dataset example is not given